# REST Service - JSON mapping for dynamic parameters

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0

Let us take the following `JSON` response which I want to return from my `REST service`,

```
 {
   "id" : 123,
   "name" : "ABC",
 }
```

For the above `JSON` response, I can create a `POJO` class like,

```
 public class Student{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   //getters and setters
 }
```

So, I can write a `GET service` to return the `Student` object which will be then transformed as `JSON`.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response get(){
       Student student = new Student();
       student.setId(123);
       student.setName("ABC");

       return Response.ok(student).build();
}
```

It works fine. Now I want to introduce optional parameters to my `JSON` response as follows,

```
{
   "id" : 123,
   "name" : "ABC",
   "params" : {"param1":"xxx","param2":342}
}
```

Here the `params` in the `JSON` response is an `Object` type and the attributes of that object are not fixed. It will vary for every request like sometime it can have 3 attributes and sometime it will have none. I don't know how to create my `POJO` class for this requirement. Can anybody suggest me a way how to do it?

Comment: What provider are you using for JSON? Jackson?

Comment: Be aware that your POJO will be most probably a DTO and not an ORM Entity. REST maps endpoints to operations and not resources to entities. By CRUD there can be overlapping ofc. but anything more than that will fail by this kind of mapping. Ofc. if this wasn't the purpose then mapping JSON to an object is completely valid.

Comment: @peeskillet, Yes I am using Jackson

Comment: Just use a `Map` for `params` in `Student` like bodo said than. It will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you don't need anything special, you should design it as like:

```
 public class Student{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   //getters and setters
   private Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>(); 

   public void add(String key, String value) {
       parameters.put(key, value);
   }

   public void addAll(Map<String, String> map) {
       parameters.putAll(map);
   }
 }
```

If you need type safety then the design is little bit complicated a consider using something like:

```
class StudentParameters {
      long param1;
      String param2;
}
```

and Student:

```
 public class Student{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   //getters and setters
   private StudentParameters studentParameters;

   public setStudentParameters(final StudentParameters studentParameters) {
       this.studentParameters = studentParameters;
   }

 }
```

Do not create complex hierarchies e.g `Map<List<List>, List<List>>` it will complicate whole structure.